# Excel Macro won't work in different files

Tags: vba, excel

I have a excel macro that I developed in one file but then when I try to run it on another file of the same format, just different data, I error out. There error I'm getting is Run-time error 424: Object required on the line "If del Is Nothing Then" below.

```
Columns("C:F").Select
Selection.ClearContents
Range("C2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "DES"
Range("C2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C2:C100")
Range("C2:C100").Select
Range("D2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-3], FIND("" |"", RC[-3]))"
Range("D2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("D2:D100")
Range("D2:D100").Select
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "STK"
Range("E2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E100")
Range("E2:E100").Select
Range("F2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "SMART/AMEX"
Range("F2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F100")
Range("F2:F100").Select
Range("G2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=LEFT(RC[-5], FIND("" %"", RC[-5]))"
Range("G2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G2:G100")
Range("G2:G100").Select
Columns("G:G").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Set rng = Intersect(Range("B2:B100"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
For Each cell In rng
    If (cell.Value) = "0 %" _
    Then
      If del Is Nothing Then
        Set del = cell
      Else: Set del = Union(del, cell)
      End If
    End If
  Next cell
  On Error Resume Next
  del.EntireRow.Delete
Set rng = Intersect(Range("A2:A100"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    For Each cell In rng
    If (cell.Value) = "CASH | CASH" _
    Then
      If del Is Nothing Then
        Set del = cell
      Else: Set del = Union(del, cell)
      End If
    End If
  Next cell
  On Error Resume Next
  del.EntireRow.Delete
```

The part that I don't understand is how is can be missing the object "del" in one file but not the other using the same macro.

Any thoughts? TIA

Comment: Where's the rest of your code?  If what you posted here is exactly what you pasted in your new workbook you are missing the top piece of your code.

Comment: The only thing left off the top was


    Sub IBFormatting()
    '
    ' IBFormatting Macro
    '
    
    '

and the "End Sub"

Comment: There has to be more somewhere.  What you have isn't declaring your variables, Rng, cell, del.  Perhaps they are Publicly declared somewhere else in your workbook and not in your new workbook.  Do a search in the original workbook vba for current project and search for Rng, cell, or del.

Comment: You may also find it helpful to add Option Explicit to the top of the module

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` turns off error handling; since error handling is never reinstated, the 2nd `On Error Resume Next` instruction is entirely redundant. `del` is an undeclared variable (is the other workbook declaring it somewhere? at the top of the module?), which makes it a runtime `Variant`, first encountered by the code as a `Variant/Empty`, which isn't a valid object reference that can be checked with `Is Nothing`. Declare your local variables with a proper `As [type]` clause, [this] problem will solve itself. Use `Option Explicit` to ensure you've declared them all.

Comment: Also note, consecutive `.Select` calls mean you have redundant code (2nd selection overrides the previous one), not to mention `Select` isn't quite needed at all in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Columns("C:F").Select
> Selection.ClearContents
> ```

You don't need `.Select` here, and don't need to work off `Selection`. Instead, do this:

```
Columns("C:F").ClearContents
```

Same for every single `.Select` call followed by a member call on `Selection`.

That will remove the annoying/redundant/inefficient `Select` calls, but won't fix the problem.

---

None of your variables are *declared*. Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of the module; VBA will then refuse to compile your code until all variables are declared.

For example:

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim del As Range
```

Now that `del` has a valid, compile-time *object type* (`Range`), at run-time when your `Is Nothing` check runs it will be a `Range` object reference without a value and the `Is Nothing` check will evaluate to `True`.

The reason you're getting an "object required" error is because `del` isn't declared, and without `Option Explicit`, the code is allowed to "declare" the variables on-the-fly at run-time (sounds cool, but is actively harmful) - every undeclared variable is a `Variant`.

While a `Variant` *can* hold an object reference, if it hasn't been assigned anything yet then its type is `Variant/Empty`, and VBA will refuse to treat that as an object reference.

This would succeed:

```
If IsEmpty(del) Then
```

But `IsEmpty` only works with `Variant`. What you want is to properly declare everything with the correct types.